# Amazon S3 consistency for versioning buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, eventual-consistency

How does versioning work with Amazon S3 consistency?
In my use case I want to upload multiple versions to the same bucket (with versioning enabled). Many writes may occur at the same time.

Will I get read-after-write-consistency, eventual consistency, no consistency or race condition (data being overwritten and lost)  for concurrent updates (PUTS) to the same objects in same bucket?

The documentation about consistency https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel has nothing about versioning.

The documentation about versioning https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html has nothing about consistency.

Comment: So you want to store multiple versions intentionally, within a few seconds of each other? That's a very unusual use-case. Why do you wish to store them as versions rather than separate objects?

Comment: There are no race conditions that would cause data loss, but concurrent upload behavior is undefined when it comes to which version is considered the "latest"  --
the version you get when you download an object from a versioned bucket without specifying a version. What's the application for concurrent writes as you describe?  Deliberate or incidental concurrency?